# Can a non-clustered index be transformed to a covering index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index, covering-index

I have a non-clustered index which includes one column. Now I want to alter the index and add additional two columns as covering columns. Is it possible? If yes, then can you, please, provide the T-SQL script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that using the `ALTER INDEX` command. But you can recreate the index using either DROP-CREATE commands or DROP_EXISTING option:

```
DROP INDEX [IDX_Name] ON [dbo].[YourTable]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Name] ON [dbo].[YourTable]
(
    [Field1] ASC
) INCLUDE ([Field2],[Field3])
GO
```

or

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Name] ON [dbo].[YourTable]
(
    [Field1] ASC
) INCLUDE ([Field2],[Field3]) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.

> To add, remove, or change the position of an index column, you must drop and recreate the index.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/modify-an-index?view=sql-server-2017)

That being said, you can use the below option to automatically drop and recreate the index:

```
DROP_EXISTING = ON
```

Please see the [CREATE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page for more details on the syntax.